# Error 65537 in AES CBC decryption

Tags: python, aes

I am currently doing a course on Coursera - Cryptography - I. There is an optional assignment, I am facing a syntactical issue with the library mentioned in it.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14'
iv = b'4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb28'
cipher = b'28a226d160dad07883d04e008a7897ee2e4b7465d5290d0c0e6c6822236e1daafb94ffe0c5da05d9476be028ad7c1d81'

obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

answer = obj.decrypt(cipher)
print(answer)
```

In the statement `obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)` 
it throws an error
`ValueError: Error 65537 while instatiating the CBC mode`
Any fixes?

Comment: The issue in your code is that key, iv, and cipher are hex-encoded, so you need to decode them to byte value before using them with your AES obj. This can be done as follows(assuming python3) `key = bytes.fromhex('140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14')`. Do the same for iv and cipher and this should work.

Comment: Your key and IV are both 32 bytes long. The key is correct for AES-256, but the IV is too long, it must be 16 bytes long for CBC mode (see [docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html#Crypto.Cipher.AES.new)). That said, you probably want to convert from hexadecimal first.

Comment: @Marc You should put that into an answer :)

Comment: The fix proposed by @MarcIlunga works: _b'Basic CBC mode encryption needs padding.\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08'_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are encoded as hex strings. You need to use the decoded arrays of bytes.

Transform them with these lines, ahead of constructing your `AES`:

```
key = bytes.fromhex(key.decode('us-ascii'))
iv = iv.fromhex(iv.decode('us-ascii'))
cipher = cipher.fromhex(cipher.decode('us-ascii'))
```

(Or, simpler, define them as regular strings to avoid the need to `.decode('us-ascii')`.)

And you'll get:

```
b'Basic CBC mode encryption needs padding.\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```